# Dreamweaver won't read the first css group of codes

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I am having a slight difficulty with my Dreamweaver and CSS... Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link href="myCss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />\
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<p id="paragraph">welcome!</p>
<button id="button"> Click here </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my css codes

```
@charset "utf-8";
<style type="text/css">
#button{
font-style:italic;
font-color:red;}    
#paragraph{
font-style:italic;}
</style>
```

My question is why is my `#paragraph` working and `#button` isn't working ?

Comment: How is it not working? Is it not shown?

Comment: Please don't tag-spam.  I see nothing in your question that has anything to do with [tag:jquery] or [tag:javascript].

Comment: where did i tag-spam javascript ???

Answer (score 0):

Remove that charset declaration before your style tag, also change `font-color` to just `color`

http://jsfiddle.net/63GRZ/

```
<p id="paragraph">welcome!</p>
<button id="button"> Click here </button>

 Here is my css codes

<style type="text/css">
#button{
font-style:italic;
color:red;}    
#paragraph{
font-style:italic;}
</style>
```

Comment: it seems like the first group of css wont work. Like in this question #button wouldnt work, but the #paragraph does work. Also if you try swapping #button and #paragraph so that #paragraph comes first and #button comes second the properties in #button would work but the #paragraph wont work.Please help

Comment: Make sure your not previewing in the Dreamweaver WYSIWYG, but in the actual browser.